# Unwanted line on barchart with jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I have a barchart with some example code I found here on stackoverflow. Here is the code for the chart:

```
var axisDates = ["Jan 19", "Jan 20", "Jan 21"]
var chartData = [2.61, 5.00, 6.00]

$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
var plot2 = $.jqplot('SubScoresGraph', [chartData], {
    title: 'Some Plot',
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            barPadding: 1,
            barMargin: 15,
            barDirection: 'vertical',
            barWidth: 50
        },
        pointLabels: { show: true }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: axisDates
        },
        yaxis: {
            tickOptions: {
                formatString: '$%.2f'
            }
        }
    },
    highlighter: {
        sizeAdjust: 7.5
    },
    cursor: {
        show: true
    }
});
```

On my page, I am including jquery 1.9.1 and the latest version of jqplot. I have a .js file with jqplot followed by the code in all of the plugin files. So essentially it is all of the jqplot javascript combined into one file.

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="combined.js"></script>
```

For some reason, though, I am getting a line through my chart and I can't figure out why. I couldn't find anything obvious in my code and when I try it in jsfiddle, it renders without the line.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have included all of the jqplot plugins, you therefore have included the Trendline plugin. When you set `$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;` it sets the trendline to show by default. You must set the show to be false explicitly.

Inside your `seriesDefaults` block, add:

```
trendline: {
  show: false
}
```